# How To: Programmatically update Tableau dashboard credentials

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-cloud

Does anyone know if Tableau has the ability to programmatically update the credentials that a dashboard uses to access a data source like Snowflake? In my use case, the password used for the snowflake data source is changed every N days, which means that a user has to also update the credentials in Tableau. Ideally, we would want to configure tableau to read the credentials automatically via an API call some credential service, etc. but I don't think that's supported via the Tableau API.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update the credentials via the Tableau Rest API. So when the credentials are updated in Snowflake you could run a script that also updates any data sources that are connected. This is from the rest api docs at [Tableau rest api](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#update_data_source_connection)

> Update Data Source Connection Updates the server address, port,
> username, or password for the specified data source connection.

```
 PUT /api/api-version/sites/site-id/datasources/datasource-id/connections/connection-id
```

JSON request body:

```
 {
   "connection": {
     "serverAddress": "newAddress",
     "serverPort": "newPort",
     "userName": "Jane Doe",
     "password": "xxxxxx",
     "embedPassword": "false",
     "queryTaggingEnabled": "false"
   }
```

}

You can also use `tableauserverclient` with python. An example of that is [here](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/update_connection.py).
Hope this works for you!